# How to implement Login in Dialogflow chatbot

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

i want to add login to my chatbot with webhook.I want to take username and password from user and send it to the webhook.

Comment: what have you tried so far? any idea in mind or any research?

Answer (score 3):

I know you didn't get much search results for that
there are following approaches

1. If you use **only Google Assistant** for chatbot then **use built in "Sign-in"** required option and then open link https://console.actions.google.com/project/**your-project-name**/accountlinking/ and in that provide your required settings like
   "Do you want signup ?" or "Login Only"
   select type of Oauth and Implicit
   Enter the endpoint url
   and bingo you will get button in Google Assistant for login
2. If you wanna add **login for web-demo** use [Detect Intent API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#detect_intent_and_agent_api)
   then go for Account linking [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) using either [code flow](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow) or [implicit flow](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-implicit-flow) but I would suggest to go for implicit flow first.
   there are various resourses out here for each language.
   Integrating API you need a **service account keys** add that to your enviornment for [Authentication](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java#authentication) to google apis
   then use [detectIntent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.DetectIntentRequest) function to get response  and **IMPORTANT use Unique session id**

hope you got it ;-)

Comment: How to get access token of a user, if an user already logged in? Actually, I've put Iframe of a chatbot in users profile section. So if the user logged in to his profile then he will able to access dialogflow, I want to know how to get that access token in that Iframe

Comment: @JayPatel did you ever find an answer to his?